# The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503' returned a non-zero code: 1 while publishing code from visual studio mac

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, docker, asp.net-core

I, am trying to pushish the code to azure using docker container service in visual studio mac. Getting lots of error as below.

```
Build started 17/06/2018 1:51:04 PM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/UOW/UOW.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Database/Data/Data.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Repo/Repository/Repository.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/ViewModels/ViewModels.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

Target ResolveProjectReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/UOW/UOW.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Database/Data/Data.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Repo/Repository/Repository.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/ViewModels/ViewModels.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/UOW/UOW.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Database/Data/Data.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Repo/Repository/Repository.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/ViewModels/ViewModels.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

Target _HandlePackageFileConflicts:
    Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Collections.Immutable.dll' and 'Reference:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.collections.immutable/1.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Collections.Immutable.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Collections.Immutable.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' and 'Reference:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/4.5.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' and 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.reflection.metadata/1.6.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' and 'Reference:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.serialization.xml/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.4.0' is greater than '4.1.1.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.win32.registry/4.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Collections.Immutable.dll' and 'Runtime:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.collections.immutable/1.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Collections.Immutable.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Collections.Immutable.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' and 'Runtime:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/4.5.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.reflection.metadata/1.6.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' and 'Runtime:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.serialization.xml/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.4.0' is greater than '4.1.2.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.accesscontrol/4.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Security.AccessControl.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.cryptography.cng/4.5.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.principal.windows/4.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.win32.registry/4.5.0/runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.win32.registry/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.accesscontrol/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Security.AccessControl.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.cryptography.cng/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.principal.windows/4.5.0/runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.principal.windows/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreGenerateRazorAssemblyInfo:
  Skipping target "_CoreGenerateRazorAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo:
  Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreCompile:
  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Touching "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Auth.API.csproj.CopyComplete".
Target GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/UOW/UOW.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Database/Data/Data.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Repo/Repository/Repository.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/ViewModels/ViewModels.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

Target GenerateBuildDependencyFile:
  Skipping target "GenerateBuildDependencyFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles:
  Skipping target "GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    Auth.API -> /Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Auth.API.dll
Target _DeletePublishIntermediateOutputPath:
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/appsettings.Development.json".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/appsettings.json".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Auth.API.deps.json".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Auth.API.dll".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Auth.API.pdb".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Auth.API.runtimeconfig.json".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Data.dll".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Data.pdb".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Repository.dll".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/Repository.pdb".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/UOW.dll".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/UOW.pdb".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/ViewModels.dll".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/ViewModels.pdb".
    Deleting file "obj/Docker/publish/web.config".
    Removing directory "obj/Docker/publish/".
    Creating directory "obj/Docker/publish/".
Target _HandlePublishFileConflicts:
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.private.datacontractserialization/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.4.0' is greater than '4.1.2.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.1/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.0.3.0' is greater than '4.0.1.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation/4.3.0/runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard1.1/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.0.3.0' is greater than '4.0.1.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation/4.3.0/runtimes/win/lib/netstandard1.1/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.0.3.0' is greater than '4.0.1.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.runtime.serialization.primitives/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.2.1.0' is greater than '4.1.2.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.serialization.xml/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.4.0' is greater than '4.1.2.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Claims.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.claims/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Security.Claims.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Claims.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.1.0' is greater than '4.0.2.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.principal/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.0/System.Security.Principal.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.1.0' is greater than '4.0.2.0'.
    Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll' and 'CopyLocal:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.xml.xmlserializer/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.1.0' is greater than '4.0.12.0'.
Target GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/UOW/UOW.csproj" (GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Database/Data/Data.csproj" (GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Repo/Repository/Repository.csproj" (GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/ViewModels/ViewModels.csproj" (GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems target(s)):

Target _CopyResolvedFilesToPublishPreserveNewest:
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/appsettings.Development.json" to "obj/Docker/publish/appsettings.Development.json".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/appsettings.json" to "obj/Docker/publish/appsettings.json".
Target _CopyResolvedFilesToPublishAlways:
    Copying file from "obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Auth.API.dll" to "obj/Docker/publish/Auth.API.dll".
    Copying file from "obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Auth.API.pdb" to "obj/Docker/publish/Auth.API.pdb".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/microsoft.identitymodel.logging/5.2.2/lib/netstandard1.4/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll" to "obj/Docker/publish/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens/5.2.2/lib/netstandard1.4/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll" to "obj/Docker/publish/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Database/Data/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/Data.dll" to "obj/Docker/publish/Data.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Repo/Repository/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/Repository.dll" to "obj/Docker/publish/Repository.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/UOW/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/UOW.dll" to "obj/Docker/publish/UOW.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/ViewModels/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ViewModels.dll" to "obj/Docker/publish/ViewModels.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/UOW/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/UOW.pdb" to "obj/Docker/publish/UOW.pdb".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Database/Data/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/Data.pdb" to "obj/Docker/publish/Data.pdb".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Repo/Repository/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/Repository.pdb" to "obj/Docker/publish/Repository.pdb".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/ViewModels/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ViewModels.pdb" to "obj/Docker/publish/ViewModels.pdb".
Target Publish:
    Auth.API -> /Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/obj/Docker/publish/
Target _TransformWebConfig:
    No web.config found. Creating 'obj/Docker/publish/web.config'
Target DockerComposeBuild:
    docker-compose  -f "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.yml" -f "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.override.yml" -p dockercompose763682937431840732 --no-ansi build auth.api
    Building auth.api
    Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS base
     ---> 7c3e298d40ac
    Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> d381faf3c759
    Step 3/17 : EXPOSE 80
     ---> Using cache
     ---> bebc20a1d897
    Step 4/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
     ---> 7c3e298d40ac
    Step 5/17 : WORKDIR /src
     ---> Using cache
     ---> f826f38a5663
    Step 6/17 : COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 9ae17dc4b020
    Step 7/17 : COPY Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj Auth.API/
     ---> Using cache
     ---> d31a7e4208e5
    Step 8/17 : RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
     ---> Running in 46bbaa0ef162
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/WebApp/WebApp.csproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/ViewModels/ViewModels.csproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/UOW/UOW.csproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/Repo/Repository/Repository.csproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/Database/Data/Data.csproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/ApiGateway/ApiGateway/ApiGateway.csproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/Advetisement/Advetisement.csproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/docker-compose.dcproj" was not found. [/src/MeroRentalDev.sln]
    Service 'auth.api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503' returned a non-zero code: 1
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : Building auth.api
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : Service 'auth.api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503' returned a non-zero code: 1.
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : 
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting
Done building target "DockerComposeBuild" in project "Auth.API.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "Auth.API.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : Building auth.api
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : Service 'auth.api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503' returned a non-zero code: 1.
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : 
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.Docker.targets(111,5): error : For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:56.57
```

Here is my docker file info

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
COPY Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj Auth.API/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Auth.API
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Auth.API.dll"]
```

Gone through these solution but no luck

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5382

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1279

https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/3278

Comment: did you fix it? Unfortunately I have the same issue and can't resolve it.